# Parallel generation of partitions

Tags: algorithm, numbers, parallel-processing, combinatorics

I am using an algorithm (implemented in C) that generates partitions of a set. (The code is here: http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/combinatorial-algorithms.html#partitions).

I was wondering if there is a way to modify this algorithm to run in parallel instead of linearly?

I've got multiple cores on my CPU and would like split up the generation of partitions into multiple running threads.

Comment: These all seem like really good answers so far but I don't fully understand them. I will need to study them a bit more and see if I can gain a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a shared collection containing every partition of the first k elements. Each thread, until the collection is empty, repeatedly removes a partition from the collection and generates all possibilities for the remaining n - k elements using the algorithm you linked to (get another k-element prefix when incrementing the current n-element partition would change the one of the first k elements).

Answer (score 0):

As you can see your referred algorithms creates counter in base `n` and each time put items with same number in one group, and in such a way partitions input.

Each counter counts from `0 to (0,1,2,...,n-1)` which means `A=`n-1+(n-2)*n+...+1*n<sup>n-1</sup>+0 numbers. So you can run your algorithm on k different thread, in first thread you should count from 0 to A/k, in second you should count from (A/k)+1 to 2*A/k and so on. means just you should add a `long` variable and check it with upper bound (in your for loop conditions) Also calculating A value and related number in base `n` format for `r*A/k for 0 <= r <= k`.

Answer (score 0):

First, consider the following variation of the serial algorithm. Take the element `a`, and assign it to the subset #0 (this is always valid, because the order of subsets inside a partition does not matter). The next element `b` might belong either to the same subset as `a` or to a different one, i.e. to subset #1. Then, the element `c` belongs to either #0 (together with `a`) or #1 (together with `b` if it's separate from `a`), or to its own subset (which will be #1 if #0={`a`,`b`}, or #2 if #0={`a`} and #1={`b`}). And so on. So you add new elements one by one to partially built partitions, producing a few possible outputs for each input - until you put all the elements. The key to parallelization is that each incomplete partition can be appended with new elements independently, i.e. in parallel with, all other variants.

The algorithm can be implemented in different ways. I would use a recursive approach, in which a function is given a partially filled array and its current length, copies the array as many times as there are possible values for the next element (which is one more than the current last value of the array), sets the next element to every possible value and calls itself recursively for each new array, with increased length. This approach seems particularly good for work-stealing parallel engines, such as [cilk](/questions/tagged/cilk) or [tbb](/questions/tagged/tbb). An implementation similar to suggested by @swen is also possible: you use a collection of all incomplete partitions and a pool of threads, and each thread takes one partition from the collection, produces all possible extensions and put those back to the collection; partitions with all elements added should obviously go into a different collection.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the c++ implementation I obtained using swen's suggestion. The number of threads depends on the value of r. For r=6 the number of partitions is the sixth bell number, which is equal to 203. For r=0 we just get a normal non-parallel program.

```
#include "omp.h"
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef long long lli;

const int MAX=10010;
const int MX=100;
int N,r=6;

int F[MAX]; // partitions first r
int Fa[MAX][MX]; // complete partitions
int P[MAX]; // first appearances first r
int Pa[MAX][MX]; // first appearances complete

int next(){// iterates to next partition of first r
    for(int i=r-1;i>=0;i--){
        P[F[i]]=i;
    }
    for(int i=r-1;i>=0;i--){
        if( P[F[i]]!=i ){
            F[i]++;
            for(int j=i+1;j<r;j++){
                F[j]=0;
            }
            return(1);
        } 
    }
    return(0);
}

int sig(int ID){// iterates to next partition in thread
    for(int i=N-1;i>=0;i--){
        Pa[ID][Fa[ID][i]]=i;
    }
    for(int i=N-1;i>=r;i--){
        if( Pa[ID][Fa[ID][i]]!=i){
            Fa[ID][i]++;
            for(int j=i+1;j<N;j++){
                Fa[ID][j]=0;
            }
            return(1);
        } 
    }
    return(0);
}

int main(){
    int N;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    int t=1,partitions=0;
    while(t || next() ){// save the current partition so we can use it for a thread later
        t=0;
        for(int i=0;i<r;i++){
            Fa[partitions][i]=F[i];
        }
        partitions++;
    }
    omp_set_num_threads(partitions);
        #pragma omp parallel
    {
        int ID = omp_get_thread_num();
        int t=1;
        while(t || sig(ID) ){// iterate through each partition in the thread
            // the current partition in the thread is found in Fa[ID]
        }
    }
}
```